# Find and Replace Image Files Between Two Folders

Tags: macos, bash, shell, filesystems

I have two folders on my Mac's hard drive.

Directory A, and Directory B

Both directories contain image files.

I need to find matching filenames is Dir A.

If I find a match overwrite the file in Dir A with the matching one from Dir B.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) is **THE** best tool for synchronizing files. It has tons of options so be sure to read the man page in detail.

```
rsync -rv --inplace --existing /path/to/dir/b/* /path/to/dir/a
```

If you want to write a script then the this should do what you are looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash

DIR_A='/path/to/dir_a'
DIR_B='/path/to/dir_b'

for file in "$DIR_B"/*; do 
    name="${file##*/}" 
    if [[ -e $DIR_A/$name ]]; then 
        echo "Match found = $name"; 
        cp "$file" "$DIR_A" 
    fi
done
```

What it does is, look for files in Directory B and extracts the file name (since we use absolute paths). It checks for that filename to see if it exists in Directory A. `-e` is the test that does that. If it is successful test then we print a message saying that `Match found` along with the filename. We then proceed to copy the file from Directory B to Directory A.

Now you may choose to remove the message that prints out to the screen and use `mv` instead of `cp` if you don't want the copy present in Directory B.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using rsync in a capistrano task and didn't even think of it.